# Find a second partial derivative of the implicitly given function $3y=z^3+3xz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am stuck at this partial derivative question. Someone earlier helped me with the first part of the question but i still cant understand the 2nd part of the question involving second order partial derivative.[image: here is the orginal question]

here is the solution that a member helped me with earlier, i can't figure out  how to get to the last line from the 3rd last line in the solution posted below. Some help with would be much appreciated.
[image: the solution by a member]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{-z}{z^2+x}$$
into the equation $$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}(z^2+x)=-2(z(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})$$

Then isolate the $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$ term by dividing both sides by $(z^2+x)$. You may need to nudge the fractions a bit for a common denominator so that it simplifies nicely.

---

Note the multiplication by $1=\frac{z^2+x}{z^2+x}$ in the second term for a common denominator:

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}(z^2+x)=-2(z(\frac{-z}{z^2+x})^2-\frac{z}{z^2+x})\\
=-2(\frac{z^3}{(z^2+x)^2}-\frac{z}{z^2+x}\cdot\frac{z^2+x}{z^2+x})\\
=-2(\frac{z^3}{(z^2+x)^2}-\frac{z^3+xz}{(z^2+x)^2})=\frac{2xz}{(z^2+x)^2}
$$

Dividing both sides once more by $(z^2+x)$ yields the desired result.

Comment: i tried substituting ∂z∂x=−zz2+x into the equation but not getting the correct answer :(

Comment: What are you getting instead? It could be that your answer is correct, but in a different (unsimplified) form.

Comment: it looks totally different with from the expected answer with z^3 and Z^2 terms in the numerator instead of (2xz). Are you able to get to the correct answer ?

Comment: I think you're close, just missing the simplification step. I'll edit my answer with the details.

Comment: thanks alot...you are awesome